# Profile does not show name

Tags: bug

My profile shows as *a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae*, though on other stacks it links to my shared profile. e.g., on Physics Stack Exchange I am user:106192, which links to my shared profile.  Here I am user:16878.

So how do I fix this?  There doesn't seem to be any edit facility.

Comment: I did think that was an interesting choice of user names...

Comment: I assume it has been fixed? I can see your user name is Peter Diehr.

Comment: Yes. I was ablevto edit the profile, and it cleared up.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where that display name came from, but you should be able to edit it on [your profile](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current). Let me know if you still have problems and I can fix it for you.

I'll check with a developer to see if we can debug the initial problem.

Comment: When I click "Network Profile" it shows my actual profile. When I click "Edit Profile" it also shows the correct information, but with the *a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae*, and the weird picture.